# Video Editing using HTML, CSS and Javascript Only

Tags: javascript, css, html, video, ffmpeg

I need to edit a video using `HTML5` and `Javascript` only. No `flash` or `ffmpeg`. I need to add title boards, background audio, (transitions, bumpers), borders etc.

I have tried `popcorn.js` but it uses CSS only and does not actually edit the video. I have even experimented with ffmpeg. FFmpeg gets the job done but takes a lot of time.

Comment: It looks like the one you linked to is in flash. I'd love to do this as well in javascript if its possible.

Comment: Check out these links:

http://mbatle.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/illusions-in-the-web-a-real-time-video-editor-built-in-html5/

and

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Manipulating_video_using_canvas

Comment: @Glogo Your second link is the answer.

Comment: For anyone else looking, you can use [vidar](https://github.com/clabe45/vidar), which lets you add layers on a timeline and export the video as a blob. It relies on built-in javascript apis, so no ffmpeg. Full discloser: I created this framework.

Answer (score 7):

When using http://www.videojs.com/ as the video player.Some of the functionality already exists in plugins for video.js but not all yet. Here are a few plugins that could add some of the functionality you would need:
    https://github.com/nicetip/videojs-speed
    https://github.com/danielcebrian/rangeslider-videojs
    https://github.com/xbgmsharp/videojs-rotatezoom
Both the video player and plugins are open source. But like I said you might have to do some development on your part for the full range of functionality that you require.